# Where does Python save a file using the path '/sdcard/file.bin'

Tags: python-3.x, android-7.0-nougat

```
import pickle 

FILE_PATH='/sdcard/file.bin'
DIC = {'usr':'jxxx@yyy.com',
       'pw':'123456' }

with open(FILE_PATH, 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(DIC, handle)

with open(FILE_PATH, 'rb') as handle:
    b = pickle.loads(handle.read())

print(b)
```

Given the code above which I executed on my Android phone in QPython, I was unable to locate file.bin on my sdcard using a file manager (File Manager HD). Can somebody tell me the absolute path of the file ? My phone is running Nougat.

Comment: When I ran this script just now on my Note 4 running marshmallow using QPython3, it saved it to the root of my internal card. `storage/emulated/0/file.bin`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out that the file is written in storage/emulated/0 !